# Inverse Fourier transform of class of infinitely differentiable function with compact support 

Tags: schwartz-distributions, fourier-analysis

For which $f \in S(R^n)$, the Schwartz class,  $\hat f \in D(R^n)$ ?

Comment: Note that such functions must be real analytic, and take a look at the Paley-Wiener theorem.

Comment: For instance, check Theorem 7.3.1 in the first volume of Lars Hormander's treatise

Comment: Just to expand Willie Wong's comment slightly: the Paley-Wiener Theorem exactly characterises the inverse Fourier transform of $L^2(-A,A)$. Since the Schwartz function $\widehat{f}$ is compactly supported *if and only if* it is in $L^2(-A,A)$ for some $A$, you immediately get the answer: $f$ extends to an entire function of exponential growth, which is $L^2$ on every horizontal line. See e.g. Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley-Wiener_theorem

I quite like the treatment in Koosis, Theory of $H_p$ spaces; many books on Hardy Spaces give it.

Comment: Let me insist with Hormander's version :)) If you read through the book, you will see that the true spirit of the result is not exactly compact support vs. exponential growth, but, more precisely: if the support is contained in a closed convex set, then you can bound the growth of the F.transform in the dual directions, and viceversa

Answer (score 2):

Gelfand-Shilov, Generalized Functions, Vol. 1 gives a rather extended discussion of this function class, as well as the corresponding class of distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, Paley wiener provides a way through it. Since we have the result,

$\check f $ = $\hat \hat f$ (This result holds for $S(R^n)$,as periodicity of Fourier transform is 4)

Let $C$  ={ $ f \in S(R^n)$ | $\hat f \in D(R^n)$ }

Then we know that $f \in C$, $\check f $ is an entire function with exponential bound. Then $f$ will also be entire function with exponential bound.

Converse of Paley-Wiener Theorem will ensure that this is exactly the class.
I hope I didn't make any mistake. :D